# flv videos in the foreground covering fancybox window in IE

Tags: fancybox, flv

my flv videos remain in the foreground hidding a part of a fancybox window; this one should be on top.
It occurs only in IE and works properly in firefox and chrome

Comment: Could you share some code / a link so we can see the problem you're describing

Comment: possible duplicate of [fancybox jquery plugin opening but youtube video still visible in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883040/fancybox-jquery-plugin-opening-but-youtube-video-still-visible-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

Set `wmode="opaque"` to your background videos. Also check that you have set a proper `DOCTYPE` so IE won't run in quirks mode.